El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'ServiceFactory' no se encontró. MediatR y Autofac. NET 8.0
Acabo de actualizar a net8.0 y las bibliotecas MediatR a la version "12.3.0" y Autofac a la version "8.0.0", el problema que me surge es un archivo (adjunto imagen)

Me surge un error en "ServiceFactory" y "serviceType", por mas que he buscado alguna solución no la encuentro.
Me sale estos error en mi lista de errores:

Espero alguna ayuda de ustedes, muchas gracias de antemano.
